# Android getResources(). where to define?

Tags: android

I have a string-array of main texts which is like words in dictionary and another string-array of sub texts which is like definition. Currently my code gets the resource from arrays.xml whenever call to the update is made and i think this is very unefficient and it feels like the response time is slow as well. However if I try to declare **private String[] mMainArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.a_maintexts);** anywhere outside this block, it doesnt work. Where should I put these getResources statements so that I only initialize my arrays once?

```
private void updateMainText(boolean next) { 
    mMainArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.a_maintexts);
    mSubArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.a_subtexts);


    if(next){
        mCurrentIndex++;
    }
    else {
        mCurrentIndex--;
    }


    mMainTextView.setText( mMainArray[mCurrentIndex]);
    mSubTextView.setText( mSubArray[mCurrentIndex]);


}
```

Comment: define `it doesnt work`

Comment: you need to call it in onCreate or after onCreate has been called.

Comment: In your onCreate, for instance. Given that you declared your String arrays in the declaration section of your Activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `private String[] mMainArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.a_maintexts);` before onCreate() function is called. If you place this line above `onCreate()` i.e. make it global, it will mean that you are trying to access resources before the activity is even created which will give you **NPE**.

Thus as @laalto and @njzk2 suggested use it either in `onCreate()` or after `onCreate()` is called.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, resource-based initialization in an `Activity` like this is best put into `onCreate()`. `onCreate()` is called only once. If there is a change to resources (for example due to orientation change), by default the activity is recreated.